# Why do my meshes do weird things after subdividing with the multires modifier?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, multiresolution

This is how I usually sculpt:

-start with the multires modifier on 1 subdivision
-when I need more detail I increase the subdivisions

But every time I click subdivide it does weird things to my mesh. It add weird creases shaped like a crate around my mesh. And every time that happens I have 
to smooth it out manually.

Here is an example:

Before pressing subdivide:
[image]

After pressing subdivide:
[image]

Anybody know what is going on?

Here's how my mesh looks like:

[image]

I had the same problem while sculpting the shell and also on every other project where I used the multires modifier.

Comment: To understand this, it would be really helpful to get a sense for the topology of your mesh. could you post a picture of the mesh in wireframe / edit mode so we can see all the vertices?

Comment: Did you add or remove any vertex after creating the multires modifier?

Comment: I am 99% sure that I didn't.